# Windows Phone 8 Silverlight vs Windows Runtime App

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I want to develop windows phone app for one of my client. I see there are 2 ways to do it i.e. Windows Phone Silverlight and Windows Runtime(Universal App). People are more favoring Windows Runtime but i also read that it will not work on Windows Phone 8 devices but Windows Phone Silverlight App will work. So i am very confused, whether to go ahead with Windows Runtime and ignore Windows Phone 8 devices or go with Windows Phone Silverlight and target Windows Phone 8 devices as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important question to answer is: what are the requirements of your client? If they demand the app to run on Windows Phone 8.0 devices, then there's no choice to be made.

If you can choose, then there are several other questions to be asked:

- Do you have experience in either WP Silverligth or Windows Runtime that you want to leverage?
- Do you want to add in a Windows desktop app as well? If so, pick Windows RT since that's supported on both platforms.
- Do you need any particular functionality only supported in WP SL or WP RT?
- Do you need any of the newer API's available in 8.1 or even 10?

Without an answer to the questions above, you can't make the correct decision.

To conclude, this is the marketshare as of Oct 25, 2015 according to [AddDuplex](http://www.slideshare.net/adduplex?utm_campaign=profiletracking&utm_medium=sssite&utm_source=ssslideview). With less than 10% running on 8.0, I don't see it as a 'must target' version if you're app would be better of running on 8.1.

[image: WP Marketshare]

Comment: Thanks for the market share chart. Now I also think, I should go with windows rt.